# Paging in hibernate subqueries

Tags: sql, hibernate, subquery, paging, detachedcriteria

I have quite a complex query that applies different layers of filtering and requires ordering/paging.

In pseudo-SQL I want to do the following:

```
SELECT ... FROM a WHERE a.id in (SELECT a.id FROM a WHERE [...] limit 10,10)
```

I use `Criteria` and `DetachedCriteria`, something like this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(xx.class, "xx");
DetachedCriteria idFilterSubQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(xx.class, "xx");
//ADD ALL FILTERS TO idFilterSubQuery
//ADD ALL OUTER_JOINS TO criteria and idFilterSubQuery
criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("id", idFilterSubQuery));
```

Now for the paging, I can't add it to `criteria`, since the outer-joins mess it up... So I need to add it to `idFilterSubQuery`... BUT, DetachedCriteria does not have `setFirstResult()` and `setMaxResult()`... But you can't add normal `Criteria` as SubQuery (I haven't found a way at least)...

I would like a solution that doesn't fetch all id's first, and the full objects afterwards (reduce a round-trip to the DB)

Any ideas how to achieve this? So either use Criteria as SubQuery or add paging to a DetachedCriteria...

I'm using Hibernate 4.2.21